# Problem with markup

Tags: support

I posted an answer https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/85871/8697

This contains the following, but the numbers I included on the 2 actions seem to prevent code formatting from working

1. Modify the `cmdline.txt` root entry to

   root=PARTUUID=24da48ba-02
2. Change the 2 lines in `/etc/fstab` to

   PARTUUID=24da48ba-01  /boot           vfat    defaults          0       2

   PARTUUID=24da48ba-02  /               ext4    defaults,noatime  0       1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Markdown Editing Help](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help), to add code formatting inside the list, indent the line with 8 spaces instead.

---

Markdown:

```
4. Preformatted text in a list item:

        Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
        That's four spaces for the list
        and four to trigger the code block.
```

Rendered:

4. Preformatted text in a list item:

   ```
   Skip a line and indent eight spaces.
   That's four spaces for the list
   and four to trigger the code block.
   ```